# writing and reading numpy nested array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to write a nested array (array of arrays per row) into a text file and read it back sucesfully but I am not sure I am doing it right, since reading the array back never seems to work.

So, I write the integer array like so:

```
    tmp_data = np.empty(shape=[len(tmp_list),3], dtype=np.object)
    for idx, item in enumerate(tmp_list):
        tmp_data[idx] = item[0][0], item[0][1], item[1]
```

the resulting first row of the array looks like so:

```
[array([1,2,3]), array([1,2,3]), array([1])]
```

I can write this using:

```
    np.savetxt(some_filename, tmp_data, fmt="%s)
```

.. but then when I read it using:

```
np.genfromtxt(some_filename)
```

I get something like `Line #89737 (got 36 columns instead of 25)`. Indeed if I look at the text file which is written, it looks like the array is broken into several lines like so:

```
 [[ 3  4  3  0  4  4  5  5  5  3  4  4  3  5  6  4  3  5  4  4  0  4  5  4
    3  4  3  0  4  4  5  5  5  3  4  4  3  5  6  4  3  5  4  4  0  4  5  4
     4  4  3  5  6  4  3  5  4  4  0  4  5  4]] [[....]] [[1]]
 ....
```

which is not intended.

In summary, I would like to write out row-wise an array of array matrix and read it back in in numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are dead set on using a text format, you could use [`numpy.ndarray.dump`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dump.html) like this:

```py
tmp_data.dump(some_filename.npy)
```

and then read it back using [`np.load(some_filename.npy)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. Yea, I did endup with a pickle like solution anyway. But, your answer does help - this is pythonic.